# Finding the days of the week within a date range using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose the following table structure:

```
Event: 
  id: integer
  start_date: datetime
  end_date: datetime
```

Is there a way to query all of the events that fall on a particular day of the week? For example, I would like to find a query that would find every event that falls on a Monday. Figuring out if the `start_date` or `end_date` falls on a Monday, but I'm not sure how to find out for the dates between.

Pure SQL is preferred since there is a bias against stored procedures here, and we're calling this from a Rails context which from what I understand does not handle stored procedures as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    event
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    dual
        WHERE   MOD(start_date - TO_DATE(1, 'J') + level - 1, 7) = 6
        CONNECT BY
                level <= end_date - start_date + 1
        )
```

The subquery iterates all days from `start_date` to `end_date`, checks each day, and if it's a `Monday`, returns `1`.

You can easily extend this query for more complex conditions: check whether an event falls on `ANY Monday OR Friday 13th`, for instance:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    event
WHERE   EXISTS  (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    dual
        WHERE   MOD(start_date - TO_DATE(1, 'J') + level - 1, 7) = 6
                OR (MOD(start_date - TO_DATE(1, 'J') + level - 1, 7) = 3 AND TO_CHAR(start_date + level - 1, 'DD') = '13')
        CONNECT BY
                level <= end_date - start_date + 1
        )
```

Note that I use `MOD(start_date - TO_DATE(1, 'J') + level - 1, 7)` instead of `TO_CHAR('D')`. This is because `TO_CHAR('D')` is affected by `NLS_TERRITORY` and should not be used for checking for a certain day of week.

This query does not use any indexes and always performs a full table scan. But this is not an issue in this specific case, as it's highly probable that a given interval will contain a `Monday`.

Even if the intervals are `1` day long, the index will return `14%` of values, if intervals are longer, even more.

Since `INDEX SCAN` would be inefficient in this case, and the inner subquery is very fast (it uses in-memory `FAST DUAL` access method), this, I think, will be an optimal method, both by efficiency and extensibility.

See the entry in my blog for more detail:

- [**Checking event dates**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/07/checking-event-dates/)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it more simply:

```
select *
from event
where 2 between to_number(trim(to_char(start_date,'D')))
            and to_number(trim(to_char(end_date,'D')))
   or (end_date - start_date) > 6
```

Comment: If I put 01.01.2003 (a Wednesday) as a START_DATE and 01.01.2004 (a Thursday) as an END_DATE, this query returns nothing. And there are sure a lot of Mondays between these dates.